# Pass values from db to form with php + json

Tags: php, sql, json, select

I successfully select some values with php and sql, which are passed to my application with JSON.

```
([{"id":"1","email":"mail@mail.org","county":"world","age":"6","gender":"unisex","poll":"option1"}]);
```

In my application i can select the values passed with jquery ajax:

```
var landmark = '<p>'+item.email+'<br>' + item.county+'<br>' + item.age+'<br>' + item.gender+'<br>' + item.poll+'</p>';
```

But instead of putting them into paragraphs, how can i just update the form with the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jquery assuming your form has elements with the following ids:

```
$('#email').val(item.email);
$('#county').val(item.county);
$('#age').val(item.age);
$('#gender').val(item.gender);
$('#poll').val(item.poll);
```

Using straight javascript:

```
document.getElementById("email").value=item.email;
document.getElementById("county").value=item.county;
document.getElementById("age").value=item.age;
document.getElementById("gender").value=item.gender;
document.getElementById("poll").value=item.poll;
```

for radio buttons:

```
if (item.gender=="Male")
    $("#male).attr("checked", "checked");
else
    $("#female").attr("checked", "checked");
```

OR more concisely -- but less robust:

```
$("#"+item.gender).attr("checked", "checked");
```

OR in javascript:

```
document.getElementById(item.gender).checked = true
```

Comment: ah - and the selector is the id of the input?

Comment: thanks! what about the radio buttons, where each input has an id?

Comment: cant get the radio to work - in the javascript, han can it see which input to check? as i see it you only get the id with the variable?

Comment: I assume you have 2 radio buttons.  One with `id="male"` another with `id="female"`.  If item.gender="male" then `$('#'+item.gender)` will select the male radio button.  Similarly with the female radio input.  Does that make sense?